# None meaning nobody

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/no-none-and-none-of?q=none), we do not use **"none"** with the meaning of **"no one/nobody"**.

> I have a lot of sporty friends. Some of them play football, but none professionally.​

Also:

> Some of the guests have very compelling backstories, but none bring any drama.

In these situations, wouldn't "none" have the meaning of "nobody"?

Thank you.

Comment: Think "none [of them]." It does not mean "nobody" (in general), just "none [of the previously mentioned people]"

Comment: Thank you, Esther :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and Cambridge are both right, in a way. I'll give Cambridge's side first.

"Nobody" normally means nobody *at all, without any qualification*, whereas "none" is always *qualified* with an "of" phrase that limits the group it applies to. Even if the "of" phrase isn't stated, it's always implied.

Like in your two examples, "none" necessarily implies "none *of my sporty friends*" and "none *of the guests*". In that context, "none" cannot possibly mean that *nobody in the world* plays football professionally or brings any drama.

Further, since "none" is always somehow qualified, it cannot be used to generally mean "nobody in the world". Let's compare two grammatically correct sentences:

1. Nobody can live without water.
2. None can live without water.

Sentence 1 is a clear, simple statement that applies to everyone. Sentence 2, however, implies an elided "none (*of the people in the world*)" and sounds rather poetic or dramatic. It's not just a standard sentence.

These are the distinctions Cambridge is making.

Now, the other side is that there are contexts where both words have the same value.

[ESPN](https://www.espn.com/racing/news/story?id=1658733)

> None were injured in transporter fire

Here, "none" is arguably used to mean "nobody", but you could also understand there's an elided "none (*of the people in the area*)".

Also, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/none) supports your position:

> **2 :** not one : NOBODY
> **3 :** not any such thing or person

I did a Google search for "none were injured", and in every case from a reputable source other than this one article from ESPN, "none" referred to a smaller group of people, like this:

> All four occupants of the GMC truck were belted and **none** were injured.

This clearly means "none *of the occupants of the truck*".

Comment: Gotube, I don't have enough words to thank you for your dedication and time spent explaining the current topic to me. It's my third day looking for any concrete answer, and I can say I've found it now.

Thanks a lot, friend!

Comment: @Portugueseporto You've made my day!!

Comment: So, when I say 'none shall sleep', who am I talking about?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Depends on the context. Or is that a reference joke that I don't get?

Comment: I think he referred to the 3 days I mentioned, ahahaha. :^)

Comment: The [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=none) suggests that 'none' is a contraction of 'no one'.

Comment: 'None shall sleep' was how I first understood the meaning of _Nessun dorma_, the opening words of a famous song.  None shall sleep, even you, oh Princess, in your cold room!